# symfony every block with spaceless

Tags: php, html, symfony, twig

How i can wrap every block code with spaceless to crop whitespaces from my twig/html

for example now i have:

```
{% block content %}

    <div class="box clearfix clearall">
        <div class="ct colcontainer">
            <div class="col-1">
                <div class="chars">
                    <table class="layout data-char">
                        <thead>

blabla

{% endblock %}
```

And when symfony try to render it, i want that symfony saw

```
{% block content %}
{% spaceless %}
    <div class="box clearfix clearall">
        <div class="ct colcontainer">
            <div class="col-1">
                <div class="chars">
                    <table class="layout data-char">
                        <thead>

blabla
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: You could use {% spaceless %} in a "all-the-content" block in you base layout. It will spaceless everything inside.

Comment: it`s not a good way for me :)

Comment: Why is it not a good way? I guess that the spaces are removed only once, when Twig files are compiled by the Twig engine, so it should not reduce the performance of the website.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Define a custom Twig tag (the copy-and-paste way)

You can define a custom Twig tag `spacelessblock` which combines [`block`](https://github.com/fabpot/Twig/blob/master/lib/Twig/Node/Block.php) and [`spaceless`](https://github.com/fabpot/Twig/blob/master/lib/Twig/Node/Spaceless.php). Then you can use `{% spacelessblock xyz %}…{% endspacelessblock %}` in your templates.  Here is how you do it the quick and dirty (copy and paste) way.

#### A new Twig node

First, define a class `Twig_Node_SpacelessBlock` (e.g. in the `Extension` directory of your bundle):

```
class Twig_Node_SpacelessBlock extends \Twig_Node_Block
{
    public function __construct($name, Twig_NodeInterface $body, $lineno, $tag = null)
    {
        parent::__construct(array('body' => $body), array('name' => $name), $lineno, $tag);
    }

    public function compile(Twig_Compiler $compiler)
    {
        // top part of Block.compile
        $compiler
            ->addDebugInfo($this)
            ->write(sprintf("public function block_%s(\$context, array \$blocks = array())\n", $this->getAttribute('name')), "{\n")
            ->indent()
        ;

        // the content of the body is treated like in Spaceless.compile
        $compiler
            ->write("ob_start();\n")
            ->subcompile($this->getNode('body'))
            ->write("echo trim(preg_replace('/>\s+</', '><', ob_get_clean()));\n")
        ;

        // bottom part of Block.compile
        $compiler
            ->outdent()
            ->write("}\n\n")
        ;
    }
}
```

#### A new Twig token parser

Our new Twig node needs to be built somewhere whenever Twig finds a `{% spacelessblock xyz %}` in a template. For that, we need a token parser which we call `Twig_TokenParser_SpacelessBlock`. We basically copy and paste [`Twig_TokenParser_Block`](https://github.com/fabpot/Twig/blob/master/lib/Twig/TokenParser/Block.php):

```
class Twig_TokenParser_SpacelessBlock extends \Twig_TokenParser
{
    public function parse(Twig_Token $token)
    {
        // …
        $this->parser->setBlock($name, $block = new Twig_Node_SpacelessBlock($name, new Twig_Node(array()), $lineno));
        // …
    }

    public function decideBlockEnd(Twig_Token $token)
    {
        return $token->test('endspacelessblock');
    }

    public function getTag()
    {
        return 'spacelessblock';
    }
}
```

#### Tell Twig about it

In your extension class:

```
class Extension extends \Twig_Extension
{
    public function getTokenParsers()
    {
        return array(
            new Twig_TokenParser_SpacelessBlock(),
        );
    }
}
```

#### Tell Symfony about it

If not already done, add the following to your your `services.yml`:

```
services:
    # …
    my.extension:
        class:     Acme\MyBundle\Extension\Extension
        tags:
          - { name: twig.extension }
```

### Better alternatives

#### Preprocessor

A better way would be to use a preprocessor to simply replace

```
{% spacelessblock xyz %}
…
{% endspacelessblock %}
```

by

```
{% block xyz %}{% spaceless %}
…
{% endspaceless %}{% endblock %}
```

which reuses all the code that already has been written in the Twig project, including possible changes.