# Automatic spaceless for twig templates

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I've a project using twig with a lot's of html templates. Unfortunatelly there is no "master"-templates which loads these templates. So each twig templates is standalone.

Is it possible to configure twig in that way, that the **%spaceless%** function will be applied to every output?
https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/spaceless.html

```
{% apply spaceless %}
    <div>
        <strong>foo</strong>
    </div>
{% endapply %}
```

Sure - it's possible to set these into every single twig template, but that's a quite dumb idea, because for every new template you have to "remember".

My idea is to implement this directly (maybe an extension) into twig, but I just didn't find the right approach for doing this? Or is there a twig option to enable this feature by default?

Comment: Independently of it's possible or not, you are using the wrong tool to solve the problem, IMO. If you are trying to save bytes for transmission, just `gzip` the output on your server.

Comment: the probably most effective solution would be to have kernel response listener look if the response is of content-type html/text (or whatever) and edit the body accordingly with a probably overall problematic regex that removes every space between `>` and `<`. (it makes pre/textarea stuff hard, as the twig docs point out)

Comment: @Jakumi you've read the docs wrong. It is stating that removing whitespace *inside* html tags is dificult, but that is not what `spaceless` does

Comment: @yivi: gzip is already in use, but we want to use the spaceless feature, too.

Comment: @DarkBee didn't read it *particularly* wrong, I just stated that the regex that removes (multiple) whitespaces between `>` and `<` (which is between html tags) has its problems. It's probably best to copy the regex the spaceless code is using. too lazy to search for it though. @Marco: what is it you're trying to achieve btw, because it's starting to sound like an A-B problem.

Comment: @Jakumi: it's just because the source code of the page should appear less readable (for humans)... and the clients request was to use twigs spaceless function... so I wonder if there is a way to use it in the desired way here.

Comment: Do note this will only "obfuscate" the source when explicitly requesting the source code. When using develop tools inside chrome/firefox the source will be optimized again for readability

Comment: @DarkBee: 100% ACK! But it's the client's will... for this a wrote in my comment "for humans". The man effect should be the usage of storage. We use a redis-cache to store the content of a website with a TTL of 15 Minutes. So the main idea behind this is to minimize the stored data inside the cache.

Comment: As stated earlier. Hook into the symfony event that the response will be presented to the client, at this point it's easier to modify the HTML content. I used to just remove all the comments and newlines, so all HTML was served on one line (my regex `$html = preg_replace(array('/<!--(.*)-->/Uis',"/[[:blank:]]+/"),array('',' '),str_replace(array("\n","\r","\t"),'',$html));`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are actually numerous options you can approach this. I think most of them are already covered here:

[symfony every block with spaceless](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12954829/symfony-every-block-with-spaceless)

You would always be in the situation to cover your code within these brackets.

But what does actually stop you from extending every template from a base template and surrounding the content block of that by `{% spaceless %}` tags?
That would be clean in the way that whenever you decide to create templates without spaceless property, you can just use the usual block.

You could also do a "replace all" across all your templates and replace "block" by our own new tag.

If you really do not want a new tag/node/something, you could also write a new token parser that looks for usual blocks and applies the `spaceless` function there if you really don't want the necessity to "remember" using `{% spaceless %}`.

Comment: you could also create a new template *loader* to just magically add the spaceless blocks depending on whether it extends or not to blocks or the whole template ... so many options (and I believe none of them good)